# Having problems while reading content from text file

Tags: php

I use text file as my "database".
I use it to search for users.
My problem is: It does search for names and it is working but it doesn't search for passwords.
I know this is confusing but please look my code, it is lot easier for understeand

**PHP**

```
<?php
$file = fopen("msskladanj_login/admins.txt","r");
$name = "Jonathan";
$password = "Jon123";

while(!feof($file)){
  $array = explode("****",fgets($file));
  $file_name = $array[0];
  $file_password = $array[1];

  if($file_password == $password && $file_name == $name){
    echo "Wellcome: ".$file_name;
  } 
}
?>
```

**admins.txt**

```
Jonathan****Jon123
Arthur****arthur123
```

I don't know what is problem and how is possible they are not the same when they are?

Comment: use $array[0] for file name.

Comment: plaintext passwords in a textfile..... baaaaad. Even for practice runs

Comment: @MihirBhatt i edited my question, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file password got white space just use trim .

```
<?php
$file = fopen("msskladanj_login/admins.txt","r");
$name = "Jonathan";
$password = "Jon123";

while(!feof($file)){
  $array = explode("****",fgets($file));
  $file_name = $array[0];
  $file_password = $array[1];

  if(trim($file_password) == trim($password) && file_name == $name){
    echo "Wellcome: ".$file_name;
  } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used same array index for password and name.   try this.

```
  <?php
    $file = fopen("msskladanj_login/admins.txt","r");
    $name = "Jonathan";
    $password = "Jon123";

    while(!feof($file)){
      $array = explode("****",fgets($file));
      $file_name = $array[0];
      $file_password = $array[1];

      if($file_name == $name ){
        echo "Wellcome: ".$file_name;
      } 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another typo here

```
if($file_password == $password && file_name == $name){
```

it should be $file_name.
If that doesn't solve it try echo-ing the filename and password before de if statement for every row and probably you will discover de difference

Comment: also try to echo the count($file_password) and count($password)